# Trying to import a new font but it doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to import a new font to implement it to the css of my p element. But the font that I imported can't be displayed for some reason.
This is my code:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(./Quicksand-Regular.ttf) format('ttf');
}

p{
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
```

Do you know what causes this problem?

Comment: You never specified a problem.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I already specified it. But basically, the font that I imported can't be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by the way, like this:

```
 src: url(./Quicksand-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
```